# IP drive Access control for GitHub

Tags: github

We have request to move from on-premise GitLab to Github repo.

Only (and actually  serious) concern is about how to allow access to repositories which are hosted on GitHub, only from Office network?

- Assume that our office static IP is 1.2.3.4.
- We have hosted our
  private repositories on GitHub (we can purchase account)
- Now user John Doe, should be able to access this repository from office
  computer and from office network.
- If user John Doe tries to access his official GitHub account and our private GitHub repo from his home computer, it should be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with GitHub to block traffic from certain IPs, since its access control is only based on accounts (and their keys), not locations. The only way to achieve this would be to use [GitHub Enterprise](https://enterprise.github.com/home), which you host on-premise behind your company's firewall.